# newcommand does not work inside figure option

Tags: macros, variable

I would like to make use of a variable that I can use multiple times to make sure all my figures are sized the same way.

At the moment I have multiple images with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={4.0cm 4.0cm 4.5cm 4.5cm},clip]{SomeImage.png}}
    \caption{Some caption describing image.}
    \label{fig: SomeImage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would now like to make a variable for the trim settings, so that I can reuse it for all figures that are similar to this one. I therefore proceed as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\ncTrimmed}{{4.0cm 4.0cm 4.5cm 4.5cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim=\ncTrimmed,clip]{SomeImage.png}}
    \caption{Some caption describing image.}
    \label{fig: SomeImage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Whatever I do to the new command, I cannot make it work. Latex keeps giving me errors like "missing } inserted" and similar. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to expand `\ncTrimmed` which you can do in the following way:

```
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\frame{\noexpand\includegraphics
    [width=\textwidth,trim=\ncTrimmed,clip]{example-image}}}\x
```

In short, the use-case here represents

```
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  <stuff>}\x
```

`\edef\x{<def>}` expands everything contained within `<def>`. Since `\endgroup` is *not* expandable, the definition of `\x` is temporary (within a `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, once `\x` is used). `<stuff>` here contains whatever you want expanded, while `\noexpand<cmd>` leaves `<cmd>` not expanded. So, after `\x` will be expanded to

```
\endgroup
  \frame{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim={4.0cm 4.0cm 4.5cm 4.5cm},clip]{example-image}}
```

(since `\textwidth` isn't expandable). You can see this is the case when using

```
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  <stuff>}\show\x
```

`\show\x` will show you what `\x` is defined as. You'll see everything remains the same, apart from an expanded `\ncTrimmed`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is happening? Seems like a lot of extra code has come together.

Comment: @user3604362 `\edef` will expand everything inside the braces and store the result in `\x`. The expansion will act on everything except non-expandable tokens (such as `\textwidth` and tokens preceded by `\noexpand`, then `\x` will contain `\frame{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim=<expansion-of-\ncTrimmed>,clip]{example-image}}`, which is what you want to do. Finally you use `\x`. The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are there only to ensure that the meaning of `\x` doesn't change in this process.

Comment: Thanks @PhelypeOleinik. I was on the road.

Comment: I am still a bit unsure why I suddenly have to expand something. Could you maybe elaborate on that or offer a good reference?

Comment: @user3604362: It all depends on the functionality implemented by `\includegraphics` when reading its key-value arguments. In some cases, subsequent processing of information is expanded anyway, but in other cases, the argument is used as-is. And when TeX *tokenizes* content (or consumes it), it would consume `\ncTrimmed` as a single element, rather than `<lx> <ly> <ux> <uy>` (four separate elements). It's not that things *suddenly* required it; it's always been like that. You've just never had to use it in this way.

Comment: Ok, now I get it.